# Microsoft UI Automation excludes ampersand in element name

Tags: c#-4.0, ui-automation

I'm using Microsoft UI automation framework to get the list of running apps. In IE, if a page has an ampersand in its title, the resulting automation element name excludes the ampersand. But it doesn't happen with same page in mozilla.

```
    GetChildren(AutomationElement.RootElement);

public AutomationElementCollection GetChildren(AutomationElement parent)
{
    AutomationElementCollection elementList;

    System.Windows.Automation.Condition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window);
    elementList = parent.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condition);

    return elementList;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting this value not from the `Window` itself, but from the `TitleBar` that sits underneath it in the UIA tree. I've tried this and its `Name` property does include the ampersand unlike the window's `Name` property. This will, however, mean that you'll need to handle various browsers differently (meaning that you'll get the value you want from the `Window` object in case of Firefox, and from the `TitleBar` object in case of IE, etc).

In general, with UIA it is a good practice to get the text from the lowest point possible - most controls that represent text, even if they implement `ValuePattern` themselves, have a `TextBox` or a `TextBlock` somewhere underneath. These 'lower' controls are much safer and predictable to work with, as property implementations may vary on other controls, as you've seen in your example.